# OData uri for filter collection empty or any eq 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

Using OData, how can I make this filter?

My class:

```
public class Aviso
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Destinatarios { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

THE uri attempt: `/odata/avisos?$filter=(Destinatarios eq null or Destinatarios/count eq 0 or Destinatarios/any(it:it/Id eq 4) )`

The goal is to return where any `Destinatarios` are 4 or collection is empty (or null).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try,

```
/odata/avisos?$filter=not Destinatarios/any() or Destinatarios/any(d: d/Id eq 4)
```

You do not need the null check as we handle null propagation for you. Also, having null collections is not a good practice in general as it causes confusion between null and empty collections.